# How do I decode unicode one line at a time in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, unicode, generator

The correct way to load unicode text from Python 2.7 is something like:

```
content = open('filename').read().decode('encoding'):
for line in content.splitlines():
    process(line)
```

(**Update**: No it isn't. See the answers.)

However, if the file is very large, I might want to read, decode and process it one line at a time, so that the whole file is never loaded into memory at once. Something like:

```
for line in open('filename'):
    process(line.decode('encoding'))
```

The `for` loop's iteration over the open filehandle is a generator that reads one line at a time.

This doesn't work though, because if the file is utf32 encoded, for example, then the bytes in the file (in hex) look something like:

```
hello\n = 68000000(h) 65000000(e) 6c000000(l) 6c000000(l) 6f000000(o) 0a000000(\n)
```

And the split into lines done by the `for` loop splits on the `0a` byte of the `\n` character, resulting in (in hex):

```
lines[0] = 0x 68000000 65000000 6c000000 6c000000 6f000000 0a
lines[1] = 0x 000000
```

So part of the `\n` character is left at the end of line 1, and the remaining three bytes end up in line 2 (followed by whatever text is actually in line 2.) Calling `decode` on either of these lines understandably results in a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf32' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 24: truncated data
```

So, obviously enough, splitting a unicode byte stream on `0a` bytes is not the correct way to split it into lines. Instead I should be splitting on occurrences of the full four-byte newline character (0x0a000000). However, I think the correct way to detect these characters is to decode the byte stream into a unicode string and look for `\n` characters - and this decoding of the full stream is exactly the operation I'm trying to avoid.

This can't be an uncommon requirement. What's the correct way to handle it?

Comment: Did you try reading the file using the codecs.open() method?

Comment: @Maulwurfn, I didn't know it existed! But I do now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`codecs.open` itself notes that `io.open` is a better option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) (note is just above link target). It's not deprecated, but only because it supports some esoteric uses (bytes->bytes codecs).

[`io.open` is available in Python 2.6 and higher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open), and provides the same behaviors as Py3's built-in `open`, is better optimized, and doesn't misbehave like `codecs.open` when it comes to stuff like line-ending conversions. The only reason to use `codecs.open` is if you need to support Python 2.5 and earlier, otherwise, `io.open` is strictly better.

```
import io

# Use with statement for guaranteed, predictable cleanup
with io.open('filename', encoding='utf-32') as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```

Incidentally, you can convert *any* already open binary file-like object to a seamless decoding text based object [using `io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), so if someone else provides you an existing file-like object in binary mode, you can still do line by line decoding implicitly with:

```
def process_file(f):
    if 'b' in f.mode:  # Or some better test...
        f = io.TextIOWrapper(f, encoding='utf-32')
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```

Answer (score 7):

How about trying somethng like:

```
for line in codecs.open("filename", "rt", "utf32"):
    print line
```

I think this should work.

The `codecs` module should do the translation for you.

Comment: Readers! Also see ShadowRanger's low-point answer near the bottom of this page: "codecs.open docs note that io.open is a better option" ...

Answer (score 4):

Try using the codecs module:

```
for line in codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf32'):
    do_something(line)
```

Comment: I selected @Simon's answer just 'cos he has fewer points, but have an upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use codecs.open instead of builtin open:

```
import codecs
for line in codecs.open('filename', encoding='encoding'):
    print repr(line)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open

Of course, I discovered this mere moments after finishing my carefully-crafted stackoverflow question.